# Проверить загружен ли файл в input type='file'

Tags: javascript

Есть `input`:

```html
<input type='file'>
```

При загрузке файла надо отправить `AJAX(put)` на сервер без нажатия на какую-либо кнопку "отправить".

Как узнать, что файл загружен? Проверять через **setInterval** каждые ~4мс? Бред. На просторах инета ничего не нашёл...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие `change`:

```js
document.getElementById('bubu').addEventListener('change', function(){
  if( this.value ){
    console.log( "Оппа, выбрали файл!" );
    console.log( this.value );
  } else { // Если после выбранного тыкнули еще раз, но дальше cancel
    console.log( "Файл не выбран" ); 
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="bubu" type="file">
```

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью jQuery

```
<input id="File1" type="file" />

if (jQuery('#File1').val()) { /* There are files */ }
```

Comment: Я так понял, если значение будет валидно, значит файл есть?

Comment: Да, в комментариях указано это.